# Alternate way around programming multiple variables

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to programming and I have got this task on my hand. I have 10 battery packs that communicate with my host system various data. I have 3 main Fail Safe processes called Fail Safe A, Fail Safe B and Fail Safe C and a No Fail. 
Here are some details:
Fail safe A is high (meaning ==1) when there are voltage or relay failures and here are example of the scenarios in which it is set.

```
(lb_fail == 00 and (lb_status == 2 or lb_status == 3 or lb_status == 6 
or lb_status ==7)) or voltage > 400 or voltage < 190 etc.
```

There about 14 different conditions during which Fail safe A is 1. The system only prints Fail safe A = 1 when any of these conditions are met. However, in order to understand which condition caused Fail safe A to be 1, I am introducing another variable reason_bit.
For example

```
reason_bitA == 0001b when (lb_fail == 00 and (lb_status == 2))
reason_bit == 0010b when (lb_fail == 00 and (lb_status == 3))
reason_bit == 0011b when (lb_fail == 00 and (lb_status == 6)) and so on.
```

Similarly there are 12 conditions for Fail safe B to be 1 and 12 conditions for fail safe C to be 1. Fail safe B and C will have reason_bitB and reason_bitC respectively.

There are Fail Safe A, B and C for each of 10 battery packs.
I only know of a primitive method of coding it this way:

```
if(Fail_safe_A1 ==1)   // Fail_safe_A1 corresponds to battery pack 1
{
  if (lb_fail ==0 & lb_status == 2)
     cout << "reason_bitA1 = 0001" << endl;
  if (lb_fail ==0 & lb_status == 3)
     cout << "reason_bitA1 = 0010" << endl; 
  if (lb_fail ==0 & lb_status == 2)
     cout << "reason_bitA1 = 0001" << endl;
}and so on.
```

I am going to have to do this 14 times Fail safe A, 12 times each for Fail safe B and C and all that is just for one pack. I have 9 more packs that needs the same thing.
Coding it this way is only increasing the lines in the code. I feel, it's not the most effective way of coding this. Could somebody please help me with inputs on how to code this more efficiently? I am using C++.
My apologies, for a long question! Appreciate your inputs and patience.

Comment: First thing you want to do is look up [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The variable names appear to be inconsistent. Anyway it seems you're heading for arrays. Look up `std::vector`, that's a nice tool.

Comment: Write down all the conditions and search for similarities. If you have 12 conditions that are disjoint, you need to write 12 conditions and handle 12 disjoint different states. Depending on library architecture you are creating, you may use some lookup table.

Comment: For your own sanity, make a nice enumeration of named constants and use them as your status codes rather than sprinkling magic numbers all around your code.  Otherwise you will end up making lots of non-obvious mistakes (e.g. entering lb_status==2 when you meant to enter lb_status==3) and if you ever need to change the status codes you will have to grovel over your entire codebase trying to figure out what magic numbers to change, rather than just updating the enum in one spot.

Comment: Sure. I will keep that in mind and use it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make yourself a class that represents all flags for a single pack:

```
class pack_status {
    int status_bits;
    int lb_fail;
    int lb_status;
    ...
};
```

Now you can make an array or a vector of `pack_status` for each battery pack, rather than duplicating the code for each one:

```
pack_status pack_stat[10];
```

Further, you could code up a class for `fail_safe`, and use it inside `pack_status` class to avoid duplicating individual conditions.